# Visual Studio - could no resolve this reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I created an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2012 on my laptop, did a bit of work on it without issues, then checked it into source control. I've checked it out on my main desktop machine (a completely fresh Git clone), and it won't compile stating that various references are missing (one of which being entityframework.dll). Looking back on my laptop, those DLLs are in my project's "bin" folder (which I didn't add to source control for obvious reasons). On my laptop, if I rename my bin folder, then I get the same compile errors. Am I incorrect in not committing certain DLL files that are in my bin folder? Surely those DLLs should be copied into the bin directory at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop probably can't find the folder to copy from.

You should add the references using NuGet (if you aren't already) and include the packages folder in source control.  (or enable package restore)

Comment: And to expand on this, it could be a reference to some library that is installed to the GAC on the laptop that aren't installed to the GAC on the desktop.  I bring this up as there are some libraries out there that require installation to the GAC in their license.  Well, more like you can't package the dll in a deployment.

Comment: Ah. The packages folder doesn't exist on my laptop. So I must have somehow accidentally removed it. I did move the directory structure of the projects in the solution around a bit - so I must have messed up doing that. This is the first time I've heard of this packages folder to be honest. I'll adjust my project and make sure it's checked into source control. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should look as to where the library references are stored in your project file. If the project is referencing copies in your bin directory then you have your project setup incorrectly.

You should maintain a libraries directory in your source control tree that id checked in like any other dependency.

The bin directory should be output only.

Comment: They are referencing the DLLs in my bin folder on the laptop. These references were added by Visual Studio when I created the ASP.NET MVC project. I've not touched them.

Comment: @Dan: You probably need to add the packages folder to source control.  Check the file location in the reference properties on the laptop.